# Create multiple relationships with py2neo

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I want to create multiple relationships between the same node using py2neo library. I used create if the relationship does not exist and merge when it exists. Here is a sample of my code :

```
def create_route(graph, sourcefile, airport_nodes):
    with open(sourcefile, encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        fieldnames = reader.fieldnames

        for row in reader:
            source_airport = row['origin']
            destination_airport = row['destination']
            source_airport_node = airport_nodes[source_airport]
            destination_airport_node = airport_nodes[destination_airport]
            node_properties = {'distance':row['distance']}
            node_properties1 = {'duration': row['duration']}
            graph.create(Relationship(source_airport_node, destination_airport_node,**node_properties1))
            graph.merge(Relationship(source_airport_node, destination_airport_node, **node_properties))
```

The problem that It get only one relationship with the last attribute which is the distance.

Thank you

Comment: Why use `merge` instead of another `create` the second time if you actually want multiple relationships?

Comment: Exactly. I used create for every type.
Thank you